# ошибка разбора входных данных

Tags: javascript, ajax

отправляю post запрос

```
        let data = {request: {jsonrpc: '2.0', method: 'login', params: params}}
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST',  '/BellGIS/login', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status !== 200) {
                alert(this.status + ': ' + this.statusText);
            } else {
                if (JSON.parse(this.responseText).result)
                    location.href = location.href;
                else showGlobalError(JSON.parse(this.responseText).error.message)
            }
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

согласно api:
параметр запроса request: Объект или массив объектов, jsonrpc - string, обязательное, всегда должно быть равно “2.0”, method - название метода, params - параметры вызова (пример: request: {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "login", "params": {"username":...., "password":...., "guest":...}})

приходит "Ошибка разбора входных данных. Передан невалидный JSON"

Comment: что у вас в переменной `params`?

Comment: Попробуйте конвертировать ваш объект до отправки, других соображений у меня нет.

Comment: `let data = JSON.stringify({request: {jsonrpc: '2.0', method: 'login', params: params}});`